# Complex two way data binding with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'll start by showing you the code before explaining the porblem :

```js
export class Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person',
  template: `
    <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="buyer">
    <!-- Code for autocomplete, when selecting a person from the autocomplete, an object person is binded to buyer -->
  `
})
export class PersonComponent {
  buyer: Person;
  
  // Code for autocomplete
}
```

My problem is when the user select a person from the autocomplete, the input is showing [object Object] which is normal. How to make it show the firstName but bind the input to the object buyer ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Change [(ngModel)]="buyer" to [(ngModel)]="buyer.firstName"  or any property name which has your buyer

```
   <input type="text" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="buyer.firstName">
```

Comment: That's the normal way for two way binding, show a string and bind it to another string like buyer.firstName.
I' trying to do a more tricky think, show a string in the input and bind it to an object where selecting it from the autocomplete.